# Seam application fails to deploy on JBoss AS5

Tags: java, jboss, maven, seam

***UPDATE: This problem goes away when I deploy as an exploded EAR i.e. by unzipping the EAR, WAR and JAR files into their constituent components. Weird.***

I have a Seam application (using 2.2.1-Final) which I'm trying to deploy on a brand-new JBoss AS 5 instance. The application is built using Maven.

When I deploy the app on JBoss the EJB portion starts up without incident, as does the Persistence stuff, but on the deploy of the web portion I get a stream of errors, all to do with missing JARs, both in the WEB-INF/lib and in the lib directory of the EAR.

The jars referred to are the Seam ones (Seam, Seam UI, Seam Remoting etc) and they are physically present in the specified locations.

Has anyone come across this before? I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what - all help gratefully accepted!

EDIT - stacktrace added. There are other errors of the same type pointing to other Seam JARs below this one:

```
2011-04-04 10:47:58,968 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/DublinHelpers-war
2011-04-04 10:47:59,265 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (main) Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/DublinHelpers-war'
2011-04-04 10:48:00,390 INFO  [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener] (main) Welcome to Seam 2.2.1.Final
2011-04-04 10:48:00,484 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner] (main) could not read entries
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\DublinHelpers-ear-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\DublinHelpers-war.war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handleArchiveByFile(URLScanner.java:123)
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handle(URLScanner.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.scanResources(URLScanner.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.deployment.StandardDeploymentStrategy.scan(StandardDeploymentStrategy.java:119)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.create(Initialization.java:130)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to this in recent days, and discovered the solution through a mixture of good googling and blind luck.

An EAR file containing Seam must only have 1 main Seam jar in it - the other jars (-excel etc) are fine, but there must only be 1 main jar. My deployment had one in the WEB-INF/lib too, brought in by dependencies through Maven. A little research through the Eclipse POM editor allowed me to determine what jar had the dependency, and exclude it in the POM. The result was a perfectly-deploying EAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Silly answer, but just to be sure. Is your WEB-INF/lib spelling WEB-dash-INF-slash-lib, and not WEB-underscore-INF-slash-lib as written in the post?

Comment: Not a silly answer, best to check enverything! My post above has a typo, though, it is definitely WEB-INF/lib. I'll edit the post. Thanks for your reply.